# How to visualize results of the distributed lag model using mgcv package

Tags: r, data-visualization, mgcv, dlm

I'm recently reading the book entitled "Generalized Additive Models --- An Introduction with R 2nd edition". When reading chapter 7.4.2--- a distributed lag model for pollution related death, I would like to know how the R code for plots at left and middle of Figure 7.15 (as follows). The GAM model is:

```r
    apl <- bam(death ~ s(time, bs="cr", k=200) + te(pm10, lag, 
            k=c(10, 5)) + te(o3, tmp, lag, k=c(8, 8, 5)), 
            family=poisson, data=dat)
```

where `pm10`, `lag`, `o3`, and `tmp` are all matrices.

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

For left figure, this can be accomplished by using `predict.gam/predict.bam` using `type = 'terms'`.
You just need to set up a new data for each `pm10` and `lag`.

For example, for `lag0`

```
pm10 <- seq(min(pm10, na.rm = T), max(pm10, na.rm = T), length = 1000)
l <- rep(0, 1000)
newdata <- data.frame(pm10 = pm10, lag = l)
```

If there are multiple smoothing terms, just add a single value to the `data.frame` as long as that value is in the range of that variable, say

```
newdata$o3 <- o3[1]
newdata$time <- time[1]
newdata$tmp <- tmp[1]
```

then do

```
pred <- predict.bam(apl, newdata = newdata, type = "terms", 
                    terms = "te(pm10,lag)")
plot(pred~pm10, type = 'l', ylim = c(-0.08, 0.08))
```

Here is my attempt to produce the first graph.
[image]

As for the middle one, the principle should be the same, in which you need to setup a new dataframe for grid combination between `o3` and `tmp` first, and lag value as before, so that grid prediction for `o3` and `tmp` would be calculated for each lag value. Then you can use `par(new=TRUE)` to overlay them together as suggested in the book. I haven't tried this one, but will give it a go later.